# Two line horizontal Nav menu

Tags: html, css

Just wondering if there is an easier way to accomplish this. Here is my dilema, I have 8 categories and I want 4 on each line and they have to left justify with the category above so they all flow correctly. My first idea was to create 4 ul with 2 li each and display my with ul's with inline-block. But I was wondering if it would be easier to use css tables instead. Any Advice?

Here is the code

```
            <ul id="nav-one" class="products-header">
                <li><a>Lasers/Inkjet Sheet Labels</a></li>
                <li><a>Thermal Labels &amp; Ribbon</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-one" class="products-header">
                <li><a>Mailing Tabs &amp; Seals</a></li>
                <li><a>Contionous Pressure Sensitive Labels</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-one" class="products-header">
                <li><a>Tray &amp; Bag Tags</a></li>
                <li><a>Heat Seal Label Paper</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-one" class="products-header">
                <li><a>Repositionable Postal Notes</a></li>
                <li><a>Paper Labels</a></li>
            </ul>
```

CSS

```
.footer-products,
.products-header {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Care to share your code with us? Otherwise giving you advice is unlikely

Comment: css tables? Tables are an html element! Also are you aware that ul can be listed also horizzontally! Last but not least there are plenty of examples on google on what you want to achieve

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

On each HTML-page, you can only have one id. So your 's can't all have nav-one as their id. You can add it as a class, though. Such as:

```
<ul class="nav-one products-header">
    <li><a>Lasers/Inkjet Sheet Labels</a></li>
    <li><a>Thermal Labels &amp; Ribbon</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would solve it in a different way, though. I'm not sure if you mean, that you want to have them in two row, such as:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Or in two columns:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

I will assume, that you want them as columns.

Here's what I would do:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <ul class="nav-ul">
  <li class="newline"><a>Lasers/Inkjet Sheet Labels</a></li>
  <li><a>Thermal Labels &amp; Ribbon</a></li>
  <li class="newline"><a>Mailing Tabs &amp; Seals</a></li>
  <li><a>Contionous Pressure Sensitive Labels</a></li>
  <li class="newline"><a>Tray &amp; Bag Tags</a></li>
  <li><a>Heat Seal Label Paper</a></li>
  <li class="newline"><a>Repositionable Postal Notes</a></li>
  <li><a>Paper Labels</a></li>
 </ul>
</div><!-- container -->
```

**CSS**

```
.container {width: 100%; display: block; overflow: hidden;}
.nav-ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.nav-ul li {float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 50%;}
.nav-ul .newline {clear: both; }
```

**THIS CODE HAVEN'T BEEN TESTED**